# How to copy data from datatable to a database table?

Tags: c#, oledbconnection

I am working on an application, wherein I want to create a table with data from a datatable.

Scenario is:

1. User selects a table and data is filled in a DataTable
2. Based on the DataTable schema I am creating a table in a temporary database (this database can be SQL Server, Oracle (user-defined))
3. Once the table is created, I want to copy data from DataTable to temp table

My code:

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(localConnString))
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();

        List<string> col = new List<string>();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        StringBuilder insertQuery = new StringBuilder();
        insertQuery.Append("Insert INTO " + tableName + " Values(");

        foreach (DataRow row in dtSchema.Rows)
        {
            string type = getColumnType(row.Field<object>("DataType").ToString());
            string column ="["+ row.Field<string>("ColumnName").ToString() + "] " + type;
            col.Add(column);
        }

        sb.Append(string.Join(",", col));

        string createTableQuery = "CREATE TABLE ["+tableName+"] (" + sb.ToString().Trim() + ")";

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(createTableQuery, con);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        // Code to copy data from DataTable to temp table
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I want to use something like `SqlBulkCopy`, but I am using OLEDB.

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: "user selects a table" - what does that mean exactly? If they are selecting from predefined templates, or deciding on columns at that point, why not directly create the table, bind to it in a datatable and fill?

Comment: My application will be used to dump data from different database.

Comment: OK I don't understand what does that mean. From database to database generally things like linked servers are used.

Comment: Example I want to merge data from 3 different tables into a single table. Table 1 is in DB 1; Table 2 in DB 2; Table 3 in DB 3. using my application user will first specify location for temporary Database where merging will take place. User will select table 1 from DB1; application will read data to DataTable; based on DataTable schema Table is created in temp database. Next step is to copy the data from DataTable to temp Db table

Comment: For SQL Server you can use SqlBulkCopy.

Comment: Yes I know. But I am using OLEDB

Comment: If server is MS SQL Server why would you ever want to use OleDb? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Not necessary that every time server db will be SQL. User can choose different server. As we are allowing the user to select Server using Data Link Properties dialogue box

Comment: The other one is Oracle? And Oracle has OracleBulkCopy, no? If you are insisting on not using bulk operations, you could create the table, create a reader and  insert command, then loop and insert (after all a datable cannot have much data in it - unless you have huge RAM).

Comment: Yes Datatable can have huge data. Also if i use looping concept; I am not sure about the table columns, as columns will vary so accordingly my insert query and and parameters will also change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182220/discussion-between-cetin-basoz-and-user2240189).

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am having almost exactly this problem. I cannot get the OracleBulkCopy class to work, the package seems corrupted. Using ManagedDataAccess to try and migrate tables from Access to Oracle. Any help would be greatly appreciated.